# VSCode Extension Icons?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just installed VSCode and went to install some extensions and noticed that no icons were showing up associated with the extensions. Yes I know thats of no real consequence but it just really stood out compared to the screen shots on the vscode page.

This is what is shown as a screen shot on the vscode page:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWkRr.jpg]

This is what I see in vscode:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAs0y.jpg]

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I found the fix was as simple as dragging the window splitter and making it larger. Icons will then appear. The view was simply too compact for the icons apparently.